# Trying to overwrite shared ..., which is different from other instances of package

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, updates, dpkg

I'm getting error messages about trying to overwrite several different files when trying to run `sudo apt-get -f install`

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-
radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 
libglapi-mesa:i386 libosmesa6:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-
radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 
libglapi-mesa:i386 libosmesa6:i386
9 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
22 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6.684 kB of archives.
After this operation, 61,4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 242693 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm2_2.4.68-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm2:i386 (2.4.68-1) over (2.4.67-1ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm2_2.4.68-
1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libdrm2/changelog.Debian.gz', 
which is different from other instances of package libdrm2:i386
Preparing to unpack .../libosmesa6_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libosmesa6:i386 (11.2.2-0intel1) over (11.2.0-1ubuntu2.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libosmesa6_11.2.2-
0intel1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared 
'/usr/share/doc/libosmesa6/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from 
other instances of package libosmesa6:i386
Preparing to unpack .../libglapi-mesa_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglapi-mesa:i386 (11.2.2-0intel1) over (11.2.0-1ubuntu2.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglapi-
mesa_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libglapi-
mesa/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of 
package libglapi-mesa:i386
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-glx_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (11.2.2-0intel1) over (11.2.0-1ubuntu2.2) 
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-
glx_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-
glx/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of 
package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already.
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.68-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.68-1) over (2.4.67-1ubuntu0.16.04.2) 
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-
amdgpu1_2.4.68-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libdrm-
amdgpu1/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of 
package libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Preparing to 
unpack .../libdrm-intel1_2.4.68-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.68-1) over (2.4.67-1ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-
intel1_2.4.68-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libdrm-
intel1/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of 
package libdrm-intel1:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already.
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-nouveau2_2.4.68-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.68-1) over (2.4.67-1ubuntu0.16.04.2) 
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-
nouveau2_2.4.68-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libdrm-
nouveau2/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of 
package libdrm-nouveau2:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already.
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-radeon1_2.4.68-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.68-1) over (2.4.67-1ubuntu0.16.04.2) 
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-
radeon1_2.4.68-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libdrm-
radeon1/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of 
package libdrm-radeon1:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already.
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (11.2.2-0intel1) over (11.2.0-1ubuntu2.2) 
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-
dri_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-
dri/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of 
package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm2_2.4.68-1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libosmesa6_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglapi-mesa_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-glx_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.68-1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-intel1_2.4.68-1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-nouveau2_2.4.68-1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-radeon1_2.4.68-1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_11.2.2-0intel1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: That's because you installed Intel drivers. They cause lots of troubles, but do not give anything useful.

Comment: but, at first i install intel's driver, there is no problem until i installed wine. So, how to fix this?

Comment: The easiest way is to re-install Ubuntu and never install the Intel drivers. It is very difficult to uninstall them and they cause onflicts with other packages.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, there's a lot of program i don't want to reinstall, maybe other solution? thanks.

Comment: You can search for uninstall manuals for these drivers. I struggled with that a lot with all by knowledge ;-) Really re-install will take less time and effort.

Comment: Installing `ppa-purge` and running it against Intel graphics' PPA should theoretically revert the updated drivers to the ones in the Ubuntu's repository but of course the best is never adding them. There's little or nothing to gain from those minor updates, current Ubuntu releases already ship with fairly updated Intel graphics drivers (open-source).

Comment: And I've said it many times, if you really want to use the Intel Graphics Update Tool, make sure your system is fully updated already: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` as recommended by Intel. All subsequent updates will be managed as all the other updates, no need to "run" the graphical tool ever again.

Comment: Ok, thanks... maybe i'll reinstall my PC.
I'm installing intel driver cz my chrome is flickering. but install intel driver is not solved my problem.

i'm new to ubuntu, and sorry for my bad english.